# Which preposition should I use after "one-sided"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have this sentence:

> In this animation, the referee is one-sided **(towards | to | for)** the team with blue jerseys.

Out of these three prepositions *("towards", "to" and "for")*, which of them would suit this situation the best?

Or, how else should I construct this sentence?

I am trying to describe that: in this animation, the referee likes and helps the team with blue jerseys but not the team with red jerseys.

Comment: If it isn't obvious that it's one-sided, there's no point in trying to identify a victim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience (AmE), "one-sided" is normally used without any dependent preposition. For example, [M-W gives a usage example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one-sided) in which it is used attributively:

> a one-sided interpretation

I just looked in several other major dictionaries and found that that is true of their examples, too. Some options that would probably work better include:

> In this animation, the referee is biased in favor of the team with blue jerseys.

and

> In this animation, the referee is partial to the team with blue jerseys.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks very much. Feel free to upvote my question :)